# 数頁あるindexビューからリンクしたshow個別ビューより元の同じ頁のindexビューに戻すことは可能ですか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

index.html.erbビューで一連に表示された２頁目のある項目を個別表示(show.html.erb)したとします。
この(show.html.erb)中に設定してある戻り戻リンク(link_to ...)でindex.html.erbビューの２頁目を表示することは出来ますか？
gem のwill_paginateか kaminariページネーション機能で出来ればよいのですが。

```
def index
  @members = Member.page(2)
end
```

での表示では２頁目に固定されしまいます。
showビューを別Windowにする事はセキュリティー上問題が生じます。
よろしくお願いします。

railsバージョン Rails 5.1.4
nagao

Comment: サンプルソースや画面イメージ等がないと、回答が付かないような気がします。正直、何がしたいのかよく伝わりません。。。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。プログラムについては下記サイト
等を参考にしてもらえればと思います。典型的なプログラムです。
http://ruby-rails.hatenadiary.com/entry/20141113/1415874683
show画面からのbackリンクでは1頁にもどるので利用者は続きを
見るためにはさらに1頁めくってから続きを見る必要があります。
もし頁を覚えていなかったら何ページかをめくって探すことになります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決できました。
下記のようなソース(元は rails g scaffold Member name:string)
変更で可能のようです。(kaminariの使用方法についてはネットにたくさん情報があります)

**Gemfile**

```
 .
 gem 'kaminari'
 .
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<tbody>
    <% @members.each do |member| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= member.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to("Show", member_path(member,current_page: @members.current_page)) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_member_path(member) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', member, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<%= link_to 'New Member', new_member_path %>
<%= paginate @members %>
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<p>
  Name:
  <%= @member.name %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_member_path(@member) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', members_path(page: @current_page) %>
```

**app/controllers/members_controller.rb**

```
 .
 .
# GET /members
# GET /members.json
  def index
     @members = Member.page(params[:page]).per(3)
  end
 .
 . 
def show
   @current_page = params[:current_page]
end
```

Comment: タグがあるせいかうまくリストされません。重要なところはindex.html.erbの<%= link_to("Show", member_path(member,current_page: @members.current_page)) %>とshow.html.erbの<%= link_to 'Back', members_path(page: @current_page) %>です。